# Poner el HTML como texto plano en electronJS

Tags: javascript, electron

Necesito que en vez de buscar y cargar un archivo HTML con `loadURL` en **electronJS** para abrir la ventana pueda pasarle el texto HTML que usara para abrir la ventana en texto plano:

Busco que:

```js
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  show: false,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
  },
});

win.loadURL(
  `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Document</title></head><body<h1>Hola mundo</h1></body></html>`
);
```

Que el codigo que puse funcione, en vez del estandar:

```js
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  show: false,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
  },
});

win.loadURL(filepath);
```

Básicamente, busco insertar código HTML en texto plano y que en base a eso me abra la ventana **electronJS** normal. Pero no encuentro una función que lo haga.

Comment: Puedes usar las etiquetas de html `<pre><pre>` y `<code>`

Comment: Como las deberia usar?

Comment: Ya tengo la solucion, la posteare

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir una  ventana nueva sin usar archivos externos, es decir, pegar el HTML en texto plano, nada mas hay que indicar el MIME y la codificacion de caracteres.

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({
   show: false,
   webPreferences: {
       nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
 filepath = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>`
win.loadURL('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(filepath))
```